# Importing module named same as package

Tags: python-3.x

I have ran into this so many times. Always struggle and forget. This time I ax. This is python3.

```
repo/
  setup.py
  abyss/
    __init__.py
    abyss.py
    some.py
```

```
# abyss.py

from abyss import some

print(some.x)
```

```
# some.py

x = 2
```

when i run `./abyss/abyss.py` I get
`ImportError: cannot import name 'some' from 'abyss'`

Comment: Where do you use `runner`?

Comment: Sorry typo in simplifing :)

Comment: `import abyss.some as some` , does that work for you?

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'abyss.some'; 'abyss' is not a package`

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @RishithEllathMeethal pbacterio did :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`some.py` is at the same level that `abyss.py`, so just using `import some` works.

Comment: Great :) I always always forget how packaging works after sometime not doing any bootstraping.